# CSRF Failed: Origin checking failed - http://localhost:8000/ does not match any trusted origins

Tags: django, permissions, csrf, csrf-token, django-rest-viewsets

Please help me solve the problem.
I was building an app consisting of Django Rest Framework and ReactJS. I used ViewSets.

my error:
[image: Screenshot of the error]

[image: Demo]

response data:

```
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: Origin checking failed - http://localhost:8000/ does not match any trusted origins."}
```

DeleteLead function in ReactApp

```
 export const deleteLead = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/leads/${id}/`)
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_LEAD,
        payload: id,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

LeadViewSet:
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializsers import LeadSerializers
from leads.models import Lead

```
# lead viewset
class LeadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()
    # permission - bu ruxsat beruvchi
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny # barcha uchun ruxsat
    ]
    serializer_class = LeadSerializers
```

LeadSerzializers:

```
# lead serializer
class LeadSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Lead
        fields="__all__"
```

Lead model:

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to set your CSRF trusted origins, allowed host and  in the settings file like this

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8000'
],
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
],
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:8000',
]
```

Comment: BROOOOOOO THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to what [Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614605) wrote, I have this:

```
python manage.py shell <<EOF
from django.conf import settings
from urllib.parse import urlparse

print([urlparse(origin).netloc.lstrip("*") for origin in settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS])
print({origin for origin in settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS if "*" not in origin})
EOF
```

Running the above will reveal what the set details for *CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS* are.

I had a situation where I was correct but then, somewhere below the settings file, this same setting was referring to a *localhost:7007*, and it was already deployed.

The above helped me detect and fix it. And if your app is inside a docker container, start it as:

> docker exec -i add-container-name-here python manage.py shell

and the other parts of it will remain the same as shown above.

[a sample of the error page on deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ascQu.png)

Answer (score 0):

To all the people who are doing this locally, this might be because you are logged-in to the Django admin panel. Logging out fixed the error.

All the CSRF solution is the right way to do it. However, if you are building a local project, this solution may work.

This is because, Django expects a CSRF token when a user session exists and since Django uses cookie sessions by default, which are susceptible to cross site request forgery (CSRF). Of course when there is no user logged in there is no reason to use CSRF because there is no cookie to protect so the request will work without the token.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue while performing the API testing in postman and i resolved the this issues by clearing the cookies in postman tool