Django csrf token cannot be read
I am writing a website with Vue as a frontend framework and django as a backend framework. I have included the csrf token in every single request from my frontend to my backend to ensure that I dont get a 403 Forbidden error. All requests are ok and function normallu. Now here is where things are not working. I sent my code as a zipped file to someone else for them to run it. The frontend and backend both run with no issues, its just that no requests to the backend can be performed. Every request returns a 403 Forbidden error, and that is due to the csrf token not being included in the request. bear in mind that is is the same code that works on one laptop but doesnt on the other. What can I do to fix this?
request from frontend to backend:


try{
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application-json',
                'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'), 
            } ,
            credentials: 'include',
        })



Value of csrf token when attempting to print it on laptop that doesnt work:


undefined



Django settings.py file:


Django settings for api project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

MEDIA_URL = '../../frontend/src/assets/Expert_imgs/'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173/','127.0.0.1']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173/',' http://127.0.0.1:5173 ','http://127.0.0.1:5173']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173 ' ,'http://localhost', 'http://127.0.0.1:5173',  'http://localhost:5173','http://127.0.0.1:5173']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ace.it.notify@gmail.com'

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 600

LOGIN_URL= 'http://127.0.0.1:5173/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5173/'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'AceIt',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "auth.User"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'



any help is appreciated

have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70612439/csrf-failed-origin-checking-failed-http-localhost8000-does-not-match-any ?

i did, it didnt help much since my settings file is structured the same way as the accepted answer

does changing your 127.0.0.1 to localhost helps ?

Ive tried that as well, but it still didnt work.

The issue ended up being that on one laptop, the frontend was running on 127.0.0.1 while on the other it was localhost. This resulted in the csrf token being set on one domain , which was 127.0.0.1 in the backend and and I was trying to read it from localhost. I just needed to add this to my vite.config file to ensure that the frontend was running on the same domain as the backend:


  server: {
    host: '127.0.0.1'
  }



